# angular5 how to submit nested reactive form

Tags: angular, form-submit, nested-forms

I was able to create nested forms (w/o submit function) by following this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/vSODkb8i7o54X3fST9VF?p=preview

Now, I would like to submit the forms, however, having 2 types of errors:

1. AppComponent.html:32 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined
2. When saving, a new line is created, but the corresponding input is not.

I've created the stackbliz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqrest

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, 
  private contractService: ContractService) { 
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.contractService.getContracts().subscribe(contracts => {
    this.contracts = contracts;
});

  this.trustForm = this.fb.group({
    contracts: this.fb.array([])
  });

  this.addContract();
}

initContract() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: '',
    emails: this.fb.array([])
  });
}

addContract() {
  const contractArray = <FormArray>this.trustForm.controls['contracts'];
  const newContract = this.initContract();

  contractArray.push(newContract);
}

removeContract(idx: number) {
  const contractsArray = <FormArray>this.trustForm.controls['contracts'];
  contractsArray.removeAt(idx);
}

onSubmit(contract: Contract) {
  this.contractService.addContract(contract);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

You have to pass the `Contract` in the form to your `onSubmit()` function.

```
<form [formGroup]="trustForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(trustForm.value.contracts)">
```

In addition, you will notice I added the `type` attribute `type="button"` to both your 'Add another email +' and 'Add another contact +' buttons. This prevents the onSubmit() event from firing when you click those buttons.

If you remove the `type` attributes I added to your buttons, you will notice they fire the onSubmit() event every time you click any of them. This is the default html button behavior. By default all buttons are of `type="submit"` unless explicitly declared otherwise. [MDN Docs: The Button Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

#### Part 2

You will want to update your `contract.service.ts` to use Rxjs Subjects. Your original approach wouldn't work because you only sent the Observable one time. With the Subject you can continue to send updates as your `Contracts` array grows or is updated.

See the updated StackBlitz attached for the working code:

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewx8bh)

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!! But, one last question, the submit button is not submitting to reflect onto the detail section. I am only having a blank additional row after submitting, have tried a couple more methods, but still not working. Appreciate if you can help!

Comment: Updated :) Please mark the answer if it helped.Happy coding!  :)

Comment: Super! looks like an area unexplored. Thanks! Happy coding too!